# Java 9 ServiceLoader runtime module loading and replacement

Tags: java, runtime, java-9, serviceloader

I just read about Java 9 module system and I'd like to ask about [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Is there any way how to add service implementation when the application is already started? How about removing some service implementation?

**Use case:** I will have some application that calculates something. The calculation algorithm will be defined in some service(Java 9 module). Are there any steps that can be done to replace this algorithm without stopping the application? When will I replace the jars is it just that the calculation will fail and I will need to catch the error and restart when the module is done loading?

Is there any other project that can support such use case?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are you saying that you want to make use of different *providers* of the algorithm(let's say) *service*?

Comment: This can be done with dynamic configurations and module layers. It's an advanced topic so probably best to get familiar with the module concepts before going there.

Comment: @nullpointer This is example, but technicaly yes and on top of that I want to replace them without down time.

Comment: @AlanBateman So it is feasible with Java 9 modules. Without any details, do you know how the interruption of ongoing calculation will work out?

Comment: It's only going to work if there are points where the application can move to the new service. In module terms, it's a new service provider module in a new layer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Assume BankController is your service .
If you want to load its implementation dynamically from dynamic path,create a new module layer and load implementation.

```
private final BankController loadController(final BankConfig config) {
    System.out.println("Loading bank with config : " + JSON.toJson(config));
    try {
        //Curent ModuleLayer is usually boot layer. but it can be different if you are using multiple layers
        ModuleLayer currentModuleLayer       = this.getClass().getModule().getLayer(); //ModuleLayer.boot();
        final Set<Path> modulePathSet        = Set.of(new File("path of implementation").toPath());
        //ModuleFinder to find modules 
        final ModuleFinder moduleFinder      = ModuleFinder.of(modulePathSet.toArray(new Path[0]));
        //I really dont know why does it requires empty finder.
        final ModuleFinder emptyFinder       = ModuleFinder.of(new Path[0]);
        //ModuleNames to be loaded
        final Set<String>  moduleNames       = moduleFinder.findAll().stream().map(moduleRef -> moduleRef.descriptor().name()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        // Unless you want to use URLClassloader for tomcat like situation, use Current Class Loader 
        final ClassLoader loader             = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        //Derive new configuration from current module layer configuration
        final Configuration  configuration   = currentModuleLayer.configuration().resolveAndBind(moduleFinder, emptyFinder, moduleNames);
        //New Module layer derived from current modulee layer 
        final ModuleLayer    moduleLayer     = currentModuleLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, loader);
        //create new instance of Implementation, in this case org.util.npci.coreconnect.CoreController implements org.util.npci.api.BankController
        final BankController bankController  = ServiceLoader.load(moduleLayer, BankController.class);
        return bankController;
    } catch (Exception e) {BootLogger.info(e);}
    return null;
}
```