# Java app with JDK 9 modules: ServiceLoader not finding service (because of Maven build?)

Tags: java, maven, java-module, serviceloader

I use a working example derived from CodeFx's book and code sample ([here](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jpms-monitor)), which I stripped to the essentials:

- a Monitor module
- a Monitor Observer module
- a Mock Observed Service module

All three are visible on Github [here](https://github.com/seinecle/demo-modules-services).

The goal is to get the Monitor module to make use of the Mock Observed Service. The 2 should not be coupled, as the Mock service could be replaced at run time by another service (using [Update4J](https://github.com/update4j/update4j) to download and add this new service on the module path for example).

But I am stuck at a basic level:

In the Monitor module, this line returns an empty List: no `ServiceObserverFactory` has been found:

```
List<ServiceObserverFactory> observerFactories = ServiceLoader
                .load(ServiceObserverFactory.class).stream()
                .map(Provider::get)
                .collect(toList());
```

I see from [codefx's readme](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jpms-monitor/tree/feature-services) that it is probably due to the Maven build: the Monitor module does not 'see' the other two modules. I should add a reference to them in Maven. But if I do so, I reintroduce some coupling, preventing me to add another service implementation at run time.

**Is there a way I can get this code example to work without reintroducing any tight coupling?**

[last note: I see the notion of "[layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644752/java-9-serviceloader-runtime-module-loading-and-replacement)" elsewhere: is it the way to go?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module layers need to be involved. A full working example is given [in this code repo](https://github.com/java9-modularity) by Paul Bakker (companion site to their book: "Java 9 Modularity").